# jQuery - use $(this) inside a function not working

Tags: jquery

I have multiple  elements made in this way

```
<img class="wind-img" src="..." data-wind="100"/>
```

i would like to set the css of these elements in this way

```
$('.wind-img').css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
        "transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)" 
    })
```

but it does not work, simply no style is set on the elements If i put the degree number, it works..

Comment: Use `.each()` or `.map()`

Comment: "inside a function" - you aren't using `this` inside any function there

Comment: sorry @Quentin i was meaning inside a jquery function..

Comment: @besmart  — It isn't inside any function at all, jQuery or otherwise. It's in an object literal which is evaluated before the resulting object is passed to `css()` as an argument.

Comment: From a more simplistic view, consider if you had a method that was `function name(a, b){}` and you called it by `name(1, 2+3)`.  The `2+3` is not passed to the method as `b`.  `5` is, because it's computed into a single value for the argument.  The same applies in this case for the object literal.

Comment: thanks all, i understand, i have to iterate over every element to apply the rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `$(this)` is valid within the `.css()` call. However you may be able to do something like this and (not technical at all) your version doesn't iterate through each element and apply the CSS but is more of a blanket statement so `$(this)` probably doesn't reference what you think it does:

```
$('.wind-img').each(function () {

    var wind = $(this).data('wind');

    $(this).css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
        "transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)" 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, `this` will be referring to something else, possibly the `window` or `document` (or some other event handler, eg the button of a button click event).

If you use `.each` then you'll be able to use `this`:

```
$('.wind-img').each(function() { 
    // "this" is now available as it's inside the .each
    $(this).css({
      "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
      "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
      "transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)" 
})
```

which can be made more efficient by reusing `$(this).data('wind')`:

```
$('.wind-img').each(function() { 
    // "this" is now available as it's inside the .each
    var windimg = $(this);
    var wind = windimg.data('wind');
    windimg.css({
      "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
      "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
      "transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)" 
})
```

if you only have one `.wind-img` then no need for the each:

```
var windimg = $('.wind-img');
var wind = windimg.data('wind');
windimg.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)",
    "transform": "rotate(" + wind + "deg)" 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wind-img').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
          "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
          "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)",
          "transform": "rotate(" + $(this).data('wind') + "deg)" 
      });
  });
});
```